# PHP nested foreach

Tags: php, foreach, nested

I thought that I understood php arrays, but it seems I don't :( 
This is my code:

```
<?php

// Create a magazines array
$magazines = array();

// Put 5 magazines on it
for($x=0;$x<5;$x++)
    $magazines[] = "Magazine " . $x ;


// Associate articles array to each magazine
foreach($magazines as $magazine){
    $articles[$magazine] = array();
    for($x=0;$x<3;$x++)
        $articles[$magazine] = $magazine . " - Article " . $x ;
}

// List them all
foreach($magazines as $magazine){
    echo $magazine . " has these articles: <br>";
    foreach($articles[$magazine] as $article)
        echo $article . "</br>";
}

?>
```

It only prints the magazines, not the articles inside each magazine. It's clear there is something I don't get about nested foreach loops. Could you please help me? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: where those articles come from?

Comment: Did you mean to put the articles inside a magazine? 'cos your code's the other way around!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the [] in the nested loop:

```
<?php

// Create a magazines array
$magazines = array();

// Put 5 magazines on it
for($x=0;$x<5;$x++)
    $magazines[] = "Magazine " . $x ;


// Associate articles array to each magazine
foreach($magazines as $magazine){
    $articles[$magazine] = array();
    for($x=0;$x<3;$x++)
        $articles[$magazine][] = $magazine . " - Article " . $x ;
}

// List them all
foreach($magazines as $magazine){
    echo $magazine . " has these articles: <br>";
    foreach($articles[$magazine] as $article)
        echo $article . "</br>";
}

?>
```

This snippet should work

Comment: Hi Fabrizio, It works! Now I understand how it works and what my mistake was. Thank you so much!

Comment: I came to the same conclusion (+1). It's also worth mentioning that this error could've been easily detected by setting `error_reporting` to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this code part:

```
$articles[$magazine][] = $magazine . " - Article " . $x ;
```